# Is it possible to scroll from UIWebView object to a UIView object?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uipagecontrol

In one of my app's user interfaces i want my app display a scrolling view(the count of the scrolled pages is dynamically set in runtime). But i want the to add UIWebView and UIView elements to the same array, so that when i scroll i will be able to display both UIWebView(let's say a web page) and some other View?

**EDIT**

I received this answer which looks as if exactly ok but doesn't work(or i couldn't to)
here is the code:
NSArray *myArray;
// Fill the array with a bunch of UIWebView and UIView objects here

```
for (id theObject in myArray)
{
    if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Can anyone please give a hend of help? I need to create a scrollable array of views(like the main page of the iPhone) but the first page(mean, view) must be a member of `UIWebView`(the others are `UIView`)

**And below is all my code(i han't try to do anything here:)**

```
  CGRect frame;
     [webView initWithFrame:frame];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:webView, [UIColor blackColor],[UIColor blackColor],  nil];
        for (int i = 0; i < colors.count; i++) {

        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;


        UIView *subview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];
        [subview setTag:i];
        if([subview tag]==2){
            UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.frame = CGRectMake(70.0f, 600.0f, 250.0f, 60);
            [button  setTitle:@"Read Messages" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                for(NSDictionary* buttonData in butDat) { 
                UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                NSString* buttonTitle = [buttonData objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSString* buttonID=[buttonData objectForKey:@"order_number"];
                [button setTitle:buttonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [button setTag:[buttonID intValue]];
                button.titleLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28];

                 CGFloat yPosition = 60.0f;
                const CGFloat buttonHeight = 85.0f;

                if (button.tag==1) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(70.0f, yPosition, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[ma.view addSubview:button];
                }
                if (button.tag==2) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(440.0f, yPosition, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[ma.view addSubview:button];   
                }
                if (button.tag==3) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(70.0f, 200.0f, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[ma.view addSubview:button];
                }
                if (button.tag==4) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(440.0f, 200.0f, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[menu_2.view addSubview:button];//****

                }
                if (button.tag==5) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(70.0f, 335.0f, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[menu_2.view addSubview:button];//****

                }
                if (button.tag==6) {
                    button.frame = CGRectMake(440.0f, 335.0f, 250.0f, buttonHeight);
                    //[menu_2.view addSubview:button];//****

                }

                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(secondAct:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [scrollView addSubview:button];
            }
                //


            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(readM:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
          //  [scrollView addSubview:button];
            [self.view addSubview:button];


            //  [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

        }
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from adding objects of type `UIWebView` and `UIView` to the same `NSArray`.

If your code needs to know if you're dealing with a `UIWebView` or a `UIView`, you can use the method `isKindOfClass:` to check:

```
NSArray *myArray;
// Fill the array with a bunch of UIWebView and UIView objects here

for (id theObject in myArray)
{
    if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Furthermore, `UIWebView` is a subclasses of `UIView` and inherits many of the same methods, making view layout the same in both cases.

From a user interface standpoint, it's probably bad practice to have scroll views inside scroll views, so you're going to want to disable scrolling of your `UIWebView` objects. If you are targeting iOS 5 and above you can use the following:

```
webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; 
webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
```

and if you're on a version of iOS lower than 5.0, you can inject the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    touchMove = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
</script>
```

To implement the javascript injection, you can use `UIWebView`'s `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method inside `webViewDidFinishLoad:`

See here for more information on `UIWebView` javascript injection: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/how-to-inject-javascript-functions-into-a-uiwebview

---

**Edit: Looking at your code, it seems as thought you're sticking a `UIWebView` and two `UIColor` objects into your array. Therefore you need to check if you're dealing with a `UIWebView` or a `UIColor`, or you'll crash on `subview.backgroundColor = [colors objectAtIndex:i];` Also you set your `UIWebView` object's frame to `CGRect frame;` which is uninitialized.**

You should populate your `NSArray` with your `UIWebView` and then two `UIView` objects with their background colors set:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
UIView *viewOne = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewOne setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
UIView *viewTwo = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewTwo setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

NSArray *viewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:webView, viewOne, viewTwo, nil];

for (id theObject in viewArray)
{
    if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIWebView class]]) {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ([theObject isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
       // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes. UIWebViews descend from UIViews. You may use them wherever you would insert a UIView as a subview, including within a UIScrollView parent view, or as an object to be inserted into an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your scroll view is not scrolling because you didn't set the contentsize property. First you have to find the content size appropriately, and then you have to set content size as

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSize];
```

at the end of code. ie; after

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
```

For a blind try, use

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1000,1000)];
```

this will definitely scroll the view!!!